# Slick slider not looping correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I have an issue with a Slick slider which you can see at http://chriswickham.co.uk/startrek/

When the slider loops, it momentarily shows the child element "hero__text" of the first slide before shooting back to the first slide as it should. I cannot figure out what's causing it. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
    <div class="gd-1of1 hero">
        <div class="hero__slide" id="hero__1">
            <div class="hero__text">
                <h1>Top 10 Reasons You Should be Playing Star Trek Online</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hero__slide" id="hero__2">
            <div class="hero__text">
                <h1>Year of Hell: What Star Trek Voyager Should Have Been</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hero__slide" id="hero__3">
            <div class="hero__text">
                <h1>What we know about Star Trek Discovery so far.</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS/SASS

```
.hero{
    height:600px;
    width:100%;
  &__slide{
    height:600px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
  }
  &__text{
    width:100%;
    padding:20px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    color:#FFF;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
  }
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hero").slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    arrows: false
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `infinite: true`

Comment: It is infinite: true by default, but adding it in makes no difference.

Comment: You should use class names for adding the background images for each slide instead of ids, as first and last slides are being cloned by slick and they do not have the id, so they do not have an image

Comment: Thanks Nora - I actually fixed the issue stated and discovered this shortly after :)